# How to make Vuex reactive to attribute/property changes in objects inside lists

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

In a vuex store file I have a variable thats initially an empty list.
This list will eventually contain users, which are objects with the form id, firstname, lastname, (...)

```
export const state = () => ({
  users: []
})
```

Throughout the lifetime of the application I push users. I have a page on my application that displays user data. All is fine, until one user needs to be updated.

```
let user = state.user.find(u => u.Id == user.Id)
user.firstname = newFirstname
user.lastname = newLastname
```

This is a problem because the page will not be updated. I also can't say which properties the user list will have because it's a list and not an object. So how do I handle this?

Comment: You should be making these changes in a mutation

Comment: I'm doing that in a mutation, inside the same file in the mutations part. How should it be done instead?

Answer (score 0):

Create your `newUser` object and then use **vue set**.

`Vue.set(array, indexOfItem, newValue) // or this.$set(...)`

For more info, see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

Comment: But it's not possible to access those variables ($set, Vue) in the Vuex store files, or am I wrong?

Comment: Just `import Vue from 'vue';` and use `Vue.set`